# Can we do forecasting on custom date instead of close date

Tags: custom-field, forecast, business-logic, forecasts-collaborative

I am using collaborative forecasting and it's using standard close date for forecast period but I have  two close dates, one for sales and second for management so I want to use forecast on custom close date which is for management. Can I do it ?
any approach and suggestion is helpful...please help.

Comment: Have you tried custom reporting. As far as I recall, standard forecasting considers standard close date for opportunities.

Comment: I tried but management want to see all details under forecast tab and forecast period should be custom close date.

Comment: try the salesforce success forum where there are more end user/sysad types

Comment: Can I achieve it through custom reporting. like in report can we use any kind of formula to put to get desire forecast on custom close date.